# Why is this C program printing line longer than MAXLINE?

Tags: c, getchar

The program should print all the input lines which length is longer than `MINLINE` 5 and shorter than `MAXLINE` 10. Ref. K&R book exercise 1.17

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define MAXLINE 10
#define MINLINE 5

int getlines(char lines[], int maxline);

int main()
{
    int length;
    char lines[MAXLINE];

    while ((length = getlines(lines, MAXLINE)) > 0)
    {
        if (length > MINLINE)
            printf("%s", lines);
    }
    return 0;
}

int getlines(char lines[], int maxline)
{
    int i, c;

    for (i = 0; i < maxline - 1 && (c = getchar()) != EOF && c != '\n'; ++i)
    {
        lines[i] = c;
    }

    if (c == '\n')
    {
        lines[i] = c;
        ++i;
    }

    lines[i] = '\0';

    return i;
}
```

Desired outpur should be like this :-

```
Hello\n
Hello\n
hi\n
excuseMe\n
excuseMe\n
longLineNotToBePrinted\n
done
done
```

but unexpectedly the program printing lines that are far longer than `MAXLINE` and sometimes printing those omitting some trailing characters.

Comment: C99 and later requires an explicit return type (of `int`) on `main()`.  You should not be writing in a 30-year old dialect of C.  It's one of a number of reasons to treat K&R with some circumspection these days.

Comment: Ok  sir, I will do it from the next time

Comment: Best way to find out is to run your program in a debugger and step thru line by line.

Comment: The code in `getlines()` reads up to MAXLINE characters at a time, but leaves the residue of a line that's longer in the input ready for the next input operation.  Your code then writes that out if the partial line is longer than 5 (6 or more).  If the tail of the line is too short, your code doesn't print it.

Comment: You need to test for maxline-3 so you can still append \n\0.

Answer (score 1):

For starters this function

```
int getlines(char lines[], int maxline)
{
    int i, c;

    for (i = 0; i < maxline - 1 && (c = getchar()) != EOF && c != '\n'; ++i)
    {
        lines[i] = c;
    }

    if (c == '\n')
    {
        lines[i] = c;
        ++i;
    }

    lines[i] = '\0';

    return i;
}
```

has undefined behavior because it can store the character `'\0'` at position `maxline` that is outside the array `lines` that has the valid range of indices `[0, maxline).`

As for your question about the output then if you entered a text that is greater than `maxline` then the function will return a string that does not contain the new line character `'\n'`. So the next string will be outputted in the same line.

Comment: regarding: `that has the valid range of indices [0, maxline).`   Since `buffer[ maxline ]` is one past the end of the array, writing to `buffer[ maxline ]` is past the end of the array so writing there is undefined behavior.  (array indexes are 0...number of elements in array -1)

Answer (score 0):

/* Updated code. Now it is working fine.
 Problems were both in main() function and in the function getlines().

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define MAXLINE 10
#define MINLINE 5

int getlines(char lines[], int maxline);

main()
{
    int length;
    char lines[MAXLINE];

    while ((length = getlines(lines, MAXLINE)) > 0)
    {
        if (length > MINLINE)
        {
/* As the input line can be longer than MAXLINE and in that case there will be no '\n' escape sequence to be stored in the lines[MAXLINE] array so we have used the if block to flow the control in such a way that when the input line is  longer than MAXLINE, the output string will be printed manually with a '\n' *newline character. */

            if (length > MAXLINE)
                printf("%s\n", lines);
            else
                printf("%s", lines);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

int getlines(char lines[], int maxline)
{
    int i, j, c;
    i = 0;

    for (j = 0; (c = getchar()) != EOF && c != '\n'; ++j)
    {

/* In the for loop this time we didn't use the condition 'j < maxline
-1' as getchar() needs to read the whole input line no matter it's length(can be greater than MAXLINE), rather we have used the 'j < maxline -1' condition as a nested if block inside the for loop. While doing this to keep the getchar() function busy reaching the last input character no matter how long the line is we have used two variable i and j to overcome the problem in such a way that i will be used to store characters in the lines[MAXLINE] array, while j will be increased untill it reaches the end of the line. */

        if (j < maxline - 1)
        {
            i = j;
            lines[i] = c;
            ++i;
        }
    }

    if (c == '\n')
    {
        if (j < maxline - 1)
        {
            lines[i] = c;
            ++i;
            ++j;
        }
        else
            ++j;
    }

    lines[i] = '\0';

    return j;
}
```